# Comparison with NaN doesn't work the way I expect?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I am doing one of the basic Javascript Kata on Codewars and the challenge is to filter all items in an array if they are not `Number` primitives.

I wrote the following:

```
const list = [ '123', 123, 2, 'aasf', '1', 1 ];

function filter_list(l) {

  const filteredArray = l.filter((item) => {
   if ( Number(item) !== NaN ) return item;
  });

  return filteredArray;

}

console.log(filter_list(list));
```

I am new to programming and cannot understand why this doesn't work. What would your solution be?

Thanks very much

Comment: `NaN !== NaN` .

Comment: Possible Dup/Related [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2652319)

Comment: Thank you, Tushar. Succinct and helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`NaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is never equals to anything including `NaN` itself ! [[**Ref**]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN)

Use [**`isNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to test the value. The `isNaN` function determines whether a value is `NaN` or not.

```js
const list = ['123', 123, 2, 'aasf', '1', 1];

function filter_list(l) {

  const filteredArray = l.filter((item) => {
    return isNaN(item);
  });
  //could be written as l.filter(isNaN);
  return filteredArray;

}

console.log(filter_list(list));
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains it! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNaN`

```js
const list = [ '123', 123, 2, 'aasf', '1', 1 ];

function filter_list(l) {

  const filteredArray = l.filter((item) => {
   if ( isNaN(Number(item)) ) return item;
  });

  return filteredArray;

}

console.log(filter_list(list));
```

**The necessity of an `isNaN` function**

Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a value is `NaN` or not, because both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an `isNaN` function.

Source : [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Thank you Sankar! That helps. :)

Comment: @NoobOfNoobs Glad about that :)